# Populate another sheet with the same columns but only selected rows

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-query

I have three columns: in column A I have `Suppliers`, B has `Order Dates` and C has `Types` ("Merchant" and "FBA").

How do I populate another sheet in the same Google Sheets with the same three columns but only with rows that have "FBA" in column C?

I want them to auto-populate so when I add another row in Sheet1 where column C is "FBA", it will automatically add that row to the next available row in Sheet2. I'm guessing I use the Index formula but am unsure how to use it.

Comment: Look at the Query or Filter functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:C,"where C ='FBA'")
```